# Number of permutations on a set given some conditions

Tags: combinatorics

I've been given the following as a homework problem:

```
Say you have a group of 12 integers, numbered 1 through 12 (1, 2, ...)
Permutations are represented as such:
The permutation in the first position is X(1).  Thus, if 
X(1) = 3, our permutation looks like (3, ...).  

How many permutations are there such that X(1) = 1 or X(2) = 2 
or X(3) = 3?
```

To try to figure this out, I started by considering a group of just 3 numbers,
(1, 2, 3).  In that group, there are `3! = 6` permutations, and 4 of them
satisfy this condition.  My intuition then, with the set of three, is that the
number of permutations is `4 = 2! + 2! + 2! - 2` (2! each for the permutations where X(1) = 1, X(2) = 2, X(3) = 3).

**However, these events aren't mutually exclusive, and I'm having trouble where the "- 2" comes from**.  It's NOT the permutations where

`X(1) = 1 and X(2) = 2 and X(3) = 3`,

since that `= 1`.

It's also not the permutations of each pair added together

`[X(1) = 1 and X(2) = 2] + [X(1) = 1 and X(3) = 3] + [X(2) = 2 and X(3) = 3]`

since that `= 3`.

It seems like it's the permutations where

`[X(1) = 1 and X(2) = 2] + [X(1) = 1 and X(3) = 3] + [X(2) = 2 and X(3) = 3] - [X(1) = 1 and X(2) = 2 and X(3) = 3]`

since that `= 2 = 1! + 1! + 1! - 0!`.  This seems kind of complex though....is this final intuition the correct one? Or where am I going wrong with my logic?

P.S. - This is HW so I'm not looking for the numerical solution to the problem.

Comment: Your final version is correct. This is the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) for three sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the inclusion-exclusion principle. Apply the formula on the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) to find the size of $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$ where $A_i$ is the set of permutations $x$ with $x(i)=i$. If you don't see why this formula holds, draw a Venn diagram with three sets intersecting.